# Image size consideration for Haar cascades

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, haar-wavelet

The OpenCV Haar cascade classifier seems to use 24x24 images of faces as its positive training data.  I have two questions regarding this:

- What are the consideration that go into selecting the training image size, besides the fact that larger training images require more processing?
- For non-square images, [some people](http://opencvuser.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-haar-cascade-classifier-aka.html) have chosen to keep one dimension at 24px, and expand the other dimension as necessary (to, say 100-200px). Is this the correct strategy?
- How does one go about deciding the size of the training images (this is a variant of question 1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- I honestly believe that there are far better parameters to be tweaked than the image size. Even so, it's a question of fine-to-coarse detection - at finer levels, you gain detail and at coarser levels, you gain structure. Also, there is a trade off: with 24x24 detection regions, there are about ~160,000 possible rectangular (haar-like) features, so increasing or decreasing also affects this number for both training/testing (this is why boosting is used to select a small subset of discriminative features).
- As you said, this is because his target was different (i.e. a pen). I think it is sensible to introduce a priori aspect ratio information to the cascade training, otherwise you would be getting detections that have square bounding boxes for a pen detector and probably suffer in performance because the training stage is picking up a larger background region around the pen.
- See my first answer. I think this is largely empirical. There are techniques for either feature scaling or building image pyramids (e.g. see [this work](http://vision.ucsd.edu/~pdollar/files/papers/DollarBMVC10FPDW.pdf)) that also mitigate the usefulness of highly controlling the choice of training target image sizes too.